# Round to machine tolerance

Tags: r, precision

I'd like to take a set of predictions and round them to machine tolerance, then  calculate a hash from those numbers.  The goal is to determine whether a complicated R process which generates those numbers has been altered. Each substantive change to the codebase to the process will generate these numbers, round them them, then compute the hash so identicalness of the process can be easily determined and tracked in a database.

I'm familiar with `all.equal()`, but using `all.equal()` would require every set of numbers to be compared with every other set of numbers directly in R--whereas what I'm envisioning the comparison of identicalness to a large set of process versions can be done just based on hashes in a table.

So my question is how would I round a numeric vector in R to a precision exactly comparable to the precision used in `all.equal`?

i.e., let's name the rounding function that accomplishes what I want `machine.round`:
`identical(machine.round(x),machine.round(y))` is `TRUE` if and only if `all.equal(x,y)` is `TRUE`.

what is the definition of `machine.round`?

```
#two vectors which are considered equal by all.equal but not by identical
x <- c(.3, .4 - .1, .5 - .2, .6 - .3, .7 - .4)
y <- c(.3, .3, .3, .3, .3)
all.equal(x,y)
identical(x,y)



#two vectors which are considered unequal by all.equal and identical:
x2 <- c(.30001, .4 - .1, .5 - .2, .6 - .3, .7 - .4)
y2 <- c(.3, .3, .3, .3, .3)
all.equal(x2,y2)
identical(x2,y2)
```

I want a function `machine.round()` that returns `TRUE` for `identical(machine.round(x),machine.round(y))` but `FALSE` for `identical(machine.round(x2),machine.round(y2))`

Comment: added a vector from R_inferno as a demonstrative example

Answer (score 1):

The default tolerance used by `all.equal` can be found by examinating its formal arguments:

```
formals(all.equal.numeric)$tolerance
sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)
```

Which evaluates to:

```
eval(formals(all.equal.numeric)$tolerance)
[1] 1.490116e-08
```

However, I don't think rounding then comparing is the correct approach. You should be checking closeness within this tolerance as `all.equal` does.

For example:

```
abs(x-y)<sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
abs(x2-y2)<sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: I think you're right and thinking about this more implies that what I'm trying to accomplish (compare hash values based on predictions which have machine error) is not possible. No matter the level of precision i round to there's a nonzero probability that numbers considered all.equal by R might end up on opposite sides of a rounding cut-off, leading to different hashes and incorrectly implying nonidenticalness